# Regarding design pattern for the search pages flow to the jsp to server page

Tags: java

I have CRM tool. I need to search the customers from search page with default filters like sites, contacts and the address what is the best way to search the result and put it to user side in a JSP. Can any one explain the request flow and the best design patterns for this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create `ConditionalExpression` and `FilterExpression` for that. Here is a piece of code where you will get an idea.

Here is the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928435.aspx)

```
        ConditionExpression condition = new ConditionExpression();  //to check whether an email already exist
        condition.AttributeName = "emailaddress1"; 
        condition.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
        condition.Values = new string[] { "any email address"};

        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
        filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
        filter.Conditions = new ConditionExpression[] { condition };

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();   //to specify which entity
        query.EntityName = EntityName.contact.ToString();
        query.ColumnSet = new AllColumns();
        query.Criteria = filter;    //here applying the filter

        BusinessEntityCollection app = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```